# Calculating total cost along multiple polylines using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, network-analyst

I'm looking to create a new sewer line. Part of the process includes making a cost analysis, which mainly centers along elevation. Areas that are lower than the treatment area need to be pumped, areas above can be gravity driven.

Normally, I'd use a Cost Path analysis to get the shortest/most cost effective path, but in this case, I have only a couple of optional paths (areas with public right of way).

With polylines determining my right of way, and a raster of my cost criteria, how can i determine which right of way is least cost?

Comment: I think you are looking at multiple iterations for each route. Create long-section, draw -1:100 line from the start vertex. First intersection with section is your pump station. Find local maximum on section after pump, i.e. start of gravity pipe. Remove part of section before 2nd point. Repeat until no new pump required. Segments between 2 pairs of points are pressure pipes. Simplistic it is.

Comment: Thanks! I actually already have the data  as afr as force/gravity/pump placement. What I'd like to do is automate a tool that allows me to calculate the minimal cost of the multiple routes of the system based on an underlying raster. So a cost flow/backlink, but only along a couple predetermined pathways.

Comment: It's network tasks then. Assign costs to each segment and find shortest/least cost path. Networkx has simple paths algorithm to find all options between 2 nodes.